# Why is EntityManager executing update() at the end?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my application I am using `executeUpdate()`, and there are in between some select statements and persist statements. I need the updates to occur immediately rather than happening at the end of all the **transactions**.

```
entityManager.createQuery("update tableb b set b.status ='ERROR' where b.id =12").executeUpdate;
entityManager.createQuery("select t from tableb t ").getresultList();
```

When I see the data in the select statement I found that the data is not updated.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: what would "flush" do, I wonder?

Comment: I tried entityManager.flush(), it doesnt help.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't help? From the information given I fail to see how anyone can offer you a solution.

Comment: I tried flush(), but its not solving the issue. I didn't see updates till the end of all transactions.